# Office is asking for picture copy of my collegiate diploma

Tags: human-resources, united-states, government

This morning, I got an email from someone in our HR department stating that our company is undergoing a government audit of our HR records. As part of this audit, HR (and supposedly the government) will need a picture copy of our collegiate diplomas. (My diploma is actually at my parents' place, over 1000 miles away).

For context, I've been with the company for about 2 years now, and I've never been asked to provide a copy of my diploma, though I'm assuming they did degree verification before I was officially hired here.

I at first recommended for this audit that they contact my university's registrar office to get degree verification, but they said that that would not do.

Has anyone been asked this before? Does this seem phishy or suspicious for the company to ask this? (It doesn't seem to me to be that hard to, say, forge a diploma, as opposed to contacting the university directly for verification...)

Comment: I've never heard of this. Did they explain why a degree verification or transcript was not good enough? The certificate is really just decorative.

Comment: Did you call your HR department and talked to a actual person to verify the authenticity of the email request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying education/degrees AFTER employment](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65345/verifying-education-degrees-after-employment)

Comment: Either phishy or typical government incompetence.  How is a potentially-doctored photo better confirmation than the university registrar?

Comment: How are they handling people who have been out of college for over 30+ years and might no longer have their diploma?

Comment: The only reasons I see to accept a paper diploma instead of contacting the registrar is if 1) the college itself no longer exists or 2) they can't verify you went there because you're in a protection program. It makes no sense to demand you take a photo of your diploma as the first choice.

Comment: I presume "picture copy" means photocopy...

Comment: I did not get an explanation of why it wasn't good enough. The email itself did come from someone within our company (and there were 2 emails sent). I have no idea how they would handle someone 30+ years out of college, personally I'm only 3 years out.

Comment: Can your University give you a offical document stating that you studied there? Where I come from the diploma is worthless compared to a detailed certified transcript, which would be the kind of document HR requires in these situations (or a note signed by someone of the Students Department, if you don't have it yet).

Comment: Tell HR the physical diploma is at your parent's place and that they cannot photocopy it for you. If HR want a copy, the only way is for you to wait 2 weeks for your folks to ship it to you. Does HR want to wait, or do they want to find another solution?

Comment: Simply have the parents scan the diploma and send the file? I find this whole question a bit strange because I work in a country where this request is standard. Why wouldn't you keep your diploma (or at least a copy or scan) with you?

Comment: I agree with Roland. Just send your diploma. The fact that you have it at your parents house says more about you than your Company.

Comment: I've made almost this same comment on an academia.SE question, but ... My diploma is 18 inches by 23 inches (46cm x 58cm) and is printed on sheepskin, as in the actual limed hide of a dead ovine. It's actually larger than that, since it's been framed. I can put my hands on it readily, but it would be quite unwieldy to photocopy. This request sounds ridiculous to my US ears.

Comment: @shoover In these days, almost everybody has a smart phone with cameras. Taking a photo of the diploma (maybe from 10 ft distance) and then get the  picture should be quite an  easy job.

Comment: And almost everybody has Photoshop or Gimp and can mix and match parts to make a photo of a diploma for any degree in any field from any university.

Answer (score 4):

It seems less effective but stupid policy out of government is not that unusual.  It strikes me that this should be less of a big deal to get your parents or a friend from your hometown to take a picture of this and text or email it to you.  It's definitely much less paperwork than getting the registrar of many universities to send confirmation of your degree.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this request sounds "phishy," and that you should verify the authenticity of the communication.

As far as I know, personnel departments can and do verify educational credentials electronically. *(Although I went to college so long ago, now, that those records are in paper boxes, and I have no idea where my diploma is.)*

A request for you to produce a photocopy of the document sounds suspicious to me ... that it might, in fact, not be an authentic request from your company's HR department.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for the state of California or some other states going through the same process, even though it sounds idiotic, there is a reason behind these. In the past, in their infinite wisdom, some supervisor, who were obviously supporters of nepotism, placed people they know or somehow referred to them by some people they know, to the positions the did not deserve, supported by the false pretenses. Let's say a certain naturalized citizen immigrant from a third world country, became a supervisor and hired all his or her cohorts from the same ethnic background from the same country, who applied for that government branch, saying they graduated from college in their home country, while they sometimes were not even high school graduates.

Knowing well, how the education and other government systems work in the third world countries, the audit teams are trying their best to verify people against who they said they are, including the degrees they purported.

My significant other is on the same boat. The college she got her associate of arts degree has been shuttered at 1999 following financial problems they were in. And no records has been filed anywhere. He diploma is nowhere to be found, thanks to countless number of moves she had been through in the past 20 years.

So, this is not really an off the wall even, but more of a witch hunt if you ask me. Some people like OP and my SO are going to be victimized even though they did nothing wrong, may be other than lack of pristine records keeping.

My 2 cents.

Comment: Auditors typically don't verify people. They verify processes and controls. So in the situation you describe they will want to confirm the employee verification process that is followed. If your SO can't find her degree certificate, I don't see it being a huge issue or likely to lead to victimization. Any auditor I know whould just increase their sample size and ask for more evidence.

Comment: A friend had this exact same problem: they were applying for University, yet their High School was shuttered years ago and any records of their diploma no longer exist. They eventually were accepted after signing an affidavit, but their situation--and your SO's--belie the fundamental problem of degrees in general: they exist only on paper and have no intrinsic value.